# jquery code to set color for a paticular string

Tags: jquery

**I have a string like this:**

```
var report = 'Verifying Wireless Interface is present and state is Disconnected:PASSED<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:PASSED<br>Add Profile to the Client:PASSED<br>Verify Profile Added Present on the Client:PASSED<br>Connecting to Access Point:PASSED<br>Verify the State is Connected:PASSED<br>Disconnecting from Access Point:PASSED<br>Verify the State is Disconnected:PASSED<br>ReConnecting to Access Point:PASSED<br>Verify the State is Connected:PASSED<br>Verify Ping to the Gateway (Access point):PASSED<br>Verify Signal Strength Greater than 75%:PASSED<br>Verify Round Trip Time not greater than 30 millieseconds:PASSED<br>Disconnecting from Access Point:PASSED<br>Verify the State is Disconnected:PASSED<br>Delete Profile to the Client:PASSED<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:Failed<br>';
```

From this, I have to set a green color for the `PASSED` string and a red color for the `Failed` string. How would it be possible...

Comment: What about putting every item which is either PASSED or FAILED into a tag (e.g. div or p) which you then can style with CSS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to wrap those words in another element

```
report = report.replace(/:PASSED/g, ':<span class="passed">PASSED</span>').replace(/:Failed/g, ':<span class="failed">Failed</span>');
```

then

```
.passed {
    color:green
}
.failed {
    color:red;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/U2j2W/)

Comment: why use /g in last ? why is necessary.

Comment: to replace the search string globally - all instances of it

Answer (score 2):

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/w3qhb/

**HTML**

```
<div id="report"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var report =  'Verifying Wireless Interface is present and state is Disconnected:PASSED<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:PASSED<br>Add Profile to the Client:PASSED<br>Verify Profile Added Present on the Client:PASSED<br>Connecting to Access Point:PASSED<br>Verify the State is Connected:PASSED<br>Disconnecting from Access Point:PASSED<br>Verify the State is Disconnected:PASSED<br>ReConnecting to Access Point:PASSED<br>Verify the State is Connected:PASSED<br>Verify Ping to the Gateway (Access point):PASSED<br>Verify Signal Strength Greater than 75%:PASSED<br>Verify Round Trip Time not greater than 30 millieseconds:PASSED<br>Disconnecting from Access Point:PASSED<br>Verify the State is Disconnected:PASSED<br>Delete Profile to the Client:PASSED<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:Failed<br>';
report = report.replace(/PASSED/ig, '<span class="p">PASSED</span>');
report = report.replace(/FAILED/ig, '<span class="f">Failed</span>');
$("#report").html(report);
```

**CSS**

```
#report span.p {color:red;}
#report span.f {color:green;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script>
var report =  'Verifying Wireless Interface is present and state is     Disconnected:PASSED<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:PASSED<br>Add Profile to the Client:PASSED<br>Verify Profile Added Present on the Client:PASSED<br>Connecting to Access Point:PASSED<br>Verify the State is Connected:PASSED<br>Disconnecting from Access Point:PASSED<br>Verify the State is Disconnected:PASSED<br>ReConnecting to Access Point:PASSED<br>Verify the State is Connected:PASSED<br>Verify Ping to the Gateway (Access point):PASSED<br>Verify Signal Strength Greater than 75%:PASSED<br>Verify Round Trip Time not greater than 30 millieseconds:PASSED<br>Disconnecting from Access Point:PASSED<br>Verify the State is Disconnected:PASSED<br>Delete Profile to the Client:PASSED<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:Failed<br>'


    var valuePassed = report.replace(/PASSED/g, '<span class="pass">PASSED</span>'); 
    var valueFianal = valuePassed.replace(/Failed/g, '<span class="fail">Failed</span>'); 
    alert(valueFianal);
</script>
```

Use fail,pass class Styling in css